# Right module vs left module

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, modules, ideals

I would like to have your help on this. Consider the following diagram summarizing the opposition left module-right module:

Left module vs Right module (s an t represent scalars)

Left module:

$$s(x + y) = sx + sy$$
$$(s_1 + s_2)x = s_1x + s_2x$$ 
$$s(tx) = (s t)x$$

Right module

$$(x + y)t = xt + yt$$
$$x(t_1 + t_2) = xt_1 + xt_2$$
$$(xs)t = x(s t)$$

Well, the thing is, I somewhere found this statement: ".....the distinction is not purely syntactical, since it implies two different associativity rules linking multiplication in a module with multiplication in a ring."

Could anyone be more specific on that and illustrate the diffence so that it becomes clear it is not simply a syntactic one. Would it be a semantic one or what exactly?

Comment: Try rewriting the axioms for a right module as a left action and you will see yourself.

Answer (score 12):

The key problem is, you want $x(nm)=((x)n)m=(nx)m=mnx=x(mn)$.

If you have a ring, $R$, you can define the opposite ring with multiplication flipped (i.e. $x*y=yx$). We can denote this ring $R^{op}$. Now if we have a left $R$-module, $M$, we can define a right $R^{op}$-module structure on $M$, by $x*m=mx$. If can be checked that $(xm)n=nmx=x(m*n)$, and all the others are trivial. This creates a bijection between the categories of left $R$-modules and right $R^{op}$-modules.

In the commutative case, clearly $R=R^{op}$, so the distinction is meaningless. But there are examples of rings with $R\neq R^{op}$. Sadly there are no simple examples to my knowledge, but some are discussed here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64370/simplest-examples-of-rings-that-are-not-isomorphic-to-their-opposites

Comment: While the existence of an isomorphism $R\to R^{\mathrm{op}}$ makes for an isomorphism between (the categories of) left and right modules, this depends on the isomorphism. Also in the case of commutative rings this can come into the way: why not turning a left $\mathbb{C}$-module into a right one by using conjugation? Of course, in the case of commutative rings there is a *natural* isomorphism with the opposite ring (the identity), so if nothing more is specified, this is used for identifying left and right modules.

Comment: @pax the 16 element ring in the post you linked is fairly simple

Comment: @rschwieb Do you mean example on message 19? There is no visible 16 number in the thread....

Comment: @JavierArias I mean [this](http://mathoverflow.net/a/64405). It's the only solution with the phrase "finite ring"

Comment: @rschwieb Ok. Thanks. I will read it tonight.

Comment: @Javier Though, I have always found these answers hard since I could never memorize them. The only ones I tend to remeber is that torsion elements of the [Brauer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer_group) with order other than 2 furnish examples, but that requires more advanced material.

Comment: Maybe this is of some interest for you all: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610613/on-publication-regarding-right-ideals-of-a-ring-and-the-sublanguages-of-science?noredirect=1#comment3282962_1610613